# Library to generate chart similar to the Libra App

Tags: android, library, graphs, charts

I'm looking for an Android library that will allow me to generate a chart similar to the [Libra app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.cachapa.libra&hl=en_US). Another example can be found in [Hacker's Diet](https://www.fourmilab.ch/hackdiet/e4/weightmonitor.html#KelvinJuly1990).

What chart type is this?